# How to convert toString in lookup using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a user document as below.

```
{
  company: ["5ffd4158f8d441032e8ac5e7"]
}
```

And I want to lookup to get companyName.

```
{
  from: 'companies',
  localField: { $toString: { $arrayElemAt: ['$company', 0] } },
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'companyInfo'
}
```

But when I do this, it says.

> $lookup argument 'localField' must be a string, found localField: { $toString: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$company", 0 ] } }: object

I converted to string using toString. But I don't know why I get this error. And the thing is I want to get company objectId in lookup directly without project above.
Could you recommend some advice? Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Introduce an `$addFields` pipeline step before the `$lookup` stage as `{ $addFields: { companyId: { $toString: { $arrayElemAt: ['$company', 0] } } }` and then update the lookup pipeline `localField` to point to the new field `companyId`

Comment: Good solution by ~chridam, there is new version of $lookup with aggregation pipeline [see](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) from mongodb 3.6

Comment: @chridam Thank you! I solved my problem by using addfields!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Const objectId=require('mongodb').objectID
```

**And use**

```
    {
company: [ObjectId("5ffd4158f8d441032e8ac5e7")]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your data type in `company` array. Ids should be stored as an `ObjectId` instead of string.
since the `_id` in companies collection has the type of `ObjectId` which is why MongoDB is unable to match and return the result.

```
{
  company: [ObjectId("5ffd4158f8d441032e8ac5e7")]
}
```

Then, you just need to pass the field name and you will get your embedded documents.

Since, in the latest version of MongoDB, it's a lot easier to `lookup` through an array of values, all we need to do is to pass the name of the array field.

```
{
  from: 'companies',
  localField: 'company',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'companyInfo'
}
```